# Unexpected behavior when adding and substracting Periods from Dates

Tags: java, java-time, period

I was experiencing some unexpected behaviors when doing date/time calculations. When it comes to daylight savings or leap years, the order of operations (months/days/hours) does matter, which is rather obvious. But it seems that the operation order is not deterministic when it comes to addition and substraction of java.time.Period?

To make more clear what I mean here an example, where I add and substract the same period from a date:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Period period = Period.ofDays(365).plus(Period.ofYears(1));
    LocalDate dateA = LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 24);
    LocalDate dateA2 = dateA.minus(period).plus(period);
    LocalDate dateA3 = dateA.plus(period).minus(period);
    System.out.println(dateA);
    System.out.println(dateA2);
    System.out.println(dateA3);

    System.out.println("---");

    LocalDate dateB = LocalDate.of(2022, 4, 24);
    LocalDate dateB2 = dateB.minus(period).plus(period);
    LocalDate dateB3 = dateB.plus(period).minus(period);
    System.out.println(dateB);
    System.out.println(dateB2);
    System.out.println(dateB3);
}
```

the output is

```
2020-04-24
2020-04-23
2020-04-24
---
2022-04-24
2022-04-24
2022-04-23
```

I was expecting that addition and substraction negate each other, so adding and substracting the same Period would always result in the initial date, but it does not. (It would require to swap the execution order from years/months/days when adding to days/months/years when substracting i assume)

Is this a bug or expected?

Comment: Is your arithmetic on the dates crossing a daylight savings boundary?

Comment: @user207421 Depending on interpretation either "no" or "that shouldn’t matter". The OP is using `LocalDate`, and `LocalDate` hasn’t got any time zone and thus is not able to be influenced by summer time (DST).

Comment: It’s a guess only: Maybe when subtracting the year is subtracted first, then the 265 days. And when adding the year is added first, then the 365 days. This means in the case of date A when subtracting you are subtracting the year across the leap day in 2020, that is 366 days, but adding only 365 days when going in the opposite direction. This causes you to end up 1 day short. For date B you have the same issue when crossing the leap day in 2024.

Comment: The documentation confirms my guess. The operations are implemented by calling [`Period.addTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html#addTo(java.time.temporal.Temporal)) and `Period.subtractFrom()`. From the documentation of the former: *... if the months are zero, the years are added if non-zero, otherwise the combination of years and months is added if non-zero. Finally, any days are added.* Same for the latter, it subtracts the year first and finally the days.

Comment: Try it with `Duration` instead

Comment: @g00se That does not work. `LocalDate.now().plus(Duration.ofDays(365))` gives *java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Seconds*. A `Duration` is time-based, think hours, minutes, seconds and fraction of second, and hence incompatible with `LocalDate`, which knows only days, months and years.

Comment: Right, yes I see

Comment: *Is this a bug or expected?* It surprised me too. On one hand date math is very often not well-defined, and probably other date-time libraries would be more in line with your expectations and mine. For example subtracting the days first and the years and months next would yield consistent results in your example situation, but still not in all situations. I would consider it more correct. On the other hand as I said, your observations agree with the documentation. So if a bug, then a bug in the design/requirements.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

The plus/minus(period) methods of `LocalDate` first add/subtract months, then days. This can lead to initially surprising behavior, especially when crossing a leap day.

### Details

Implementation of `LocalDate`'s method `plus` is as follows:

```
if (amountToAdd instanceof Period periodToAdd) {
    return plusMonths(periodToAdd.toTotalMonths()).plusDays(periodToAdd.getDays());
}
...
```

A similar approach is taken for the minus method.

For a period specified in the question:

```
Period period = Period.ofDays(365).plus(Period.ofYears(1));
```

it'll first subtract(add) 12 months and then subtract(add) 365 days.

This is why `dateA.minus(period).plus(period)` results in `2020-04-23` (and not in original date - `2020-04-24`). When subtracting, we cross over 2020-02-29 via the `minusMonths` path (thus skipping 29 days as one month). However, on the return journey, we cross it via the `plusDays` path (resulting in one day "missing").

### Example

Illustrated in four steps:

```
LocalDate dateA = LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 24);
// 2020-04-24

LocalDate dateAMinusMonths = dateA.minusMonths(12);
// 2019-04-24

LocalDate dateAMinusMonthsMinusDays = dateAMinusMonths.minusDays(365);
// 2018-04-24

LocalDate dateAMinusMonthsMinusDaysPlusMonths = dateAMinusMonthsMinusDays.plusMonths(12);
// 2019-04-24

LocalDate dateAMinusMonthsMinusDaysPlusMonthsPlusDays = dateAMinusMonthsMinusDaysPlusMonths.plusDays(365);
// 2020-04-23
```

Similarly, adding 365 days to any date may not always result in the same date and day in the next year.

### Bug? It depends...

On one hand, it seems odd that adding and subtracting the same period does not lead to the same date; there is a lack of symmetry. This symmetry could be achieved if we subtracted days first when subtracting, and then subtracted months.

On the other hand, there is a symmetry in that it does not matter whether we add or subtract periods; we always add/subtract months first (if applicable), then days.

Comment: I am aware of why the behavior is th eway it is. The reason why the result is a bit problematic to me and why I would tend more towards "bug":
The naming `plus()`and `minus()` imply that normal arithmetic rules apply. and that is not the case, one of the most important arithmetic properties is the the associative law of addition and multiplication, `a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c`.
This law is violated in this case, a + (b + c) is not (a + b) + c.